# Azure staticwebapp not allowing to add config with "&" in value using Azure CLI in terminal

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app

I am using Azure CLI to use the azure. I am trying to create a staticwebapp and later try to add the configuration from CLI.

I tried to run this

```
az staticwebapp appsettings set -n appname --setting-names MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb+srv://anirudha:testing@cluster4340.v45343.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

I am getting error

```
'w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I go to portal and seen before &w=majority is added into configuration but this part is not added after &.

I tried to put singlequote and key=("val") but none of them working for me. I found this in azure app config github repo.

Anyone have idea how to make it work from CLI

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this mistake only here? I mean missing space `appname--setting-names`. It should be `appname --setting-names`.

Comment: Sorry only here, it's have space in actual, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--setting-names` property accepts the app settings in **'key=value'** format as mentioned here in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-appsettings-set) of az staticwebapp app settings set cmdlet.

You need to change the above shared cmdlet to the below:

```
az staticwebapp appsettings set -n <staticWebAppName> --setting-names 'MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=<AppsettingValue>'
```

I have tested this and it is working fine from my end Here is the sample output screenshot for your reference:

[image]

***Updated Answer:***

Alternatively, you can use this PowerShell cmdlet
([New-AzStaticWebAppSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azstaticwebappsetting?view=azps-8.2.0)) to update the app settings of the static web app

```
New-AzStaticWebAppSetting -ResourceGroupName resourceGroup -Name staticweb01 -AppSetting @{'function01' = 'value01'; 'function02' = 'value02' }
```

Comment: Actually I am using it from powershell on windows, I tried with Cmd as well. Both are failing. I updated the post with powershell error

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta, As mentioned in my answer can you pass the --setting-names in single quotes as shown below:

https://i.imgur.com/X7MVh3V.png

Comment: I tried that way too in powershell. I have attached screenshot. Please check

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta the command execution got successful can check your static web app configuration whether were you able to see those app setting or not

Comment: Yes, but only partial value is there, everything after & is not there in config

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Lets join this chat room and continue our discussion https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247813/73604495